# How to detect clicks on specific links in page with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, click, greasemonkey

Ok... one of my virtual pet sites was down so I decided to tweak a Greasemonkey script for another site... the original script just pops up an alert when you find an egg so you don't click past it - I thought it would be simple to count how many eggs I came across.  After 2 hours I finally found a way to keep a variable past page reloads - SUCCESS!!  Then I decided I wanted to  keep track of how many "steps" I was taking... ARGGGG!!!! Should be simple but isn't!
On the page there are three possible explore links to click (shows image not link).  3 hours later I found the event listener and can make an alert popup when I click anywhere on the page, but how do I check for clicks only on 1 of those 3 links?  All 3 links have the same general format:  `http://unicreatures.com/explore.php?area=***&id=***&key=****` where the `*` are changeable.

Target page `http://unicreatures.com/explore.php?area=grassland` should be accessible without an account, if not let me know and I'll grab the source code.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Unicreatures Egg pop-up
// @namespace Unicreatures Egg pop-up
// @description Unicreatures Egg pop-up
// @include http://unicreatures.com/explore.php*
// @include http://www.unicreatures.com/explore.php*
// ==/UserScript==

var y = document.body.innerHTML;

//document.addEventListener('click', function(){alert('page clicked')}, true);

if(y.indexOf("You find a Noble")> 0)
{
alert('Noble Egg Alert');
}

if(y.indexOf("You find an Exalted")> 0)
{
localStorage.exaltedEggCount=Number(localStorage.exaltedEggCount)+1;
alert('Exalted Egg Alert '+localStorage.exaltedEggCount);
}

if(y.indexOf("egg nearby!")> 0)
{
localStorage.eggCount=Number(localStorage.eggCount)+1;

alert('Egg Alert '+localStorage.eggCount);
}
```

I do realize that the way the if statements are written that I get double alerts if either of the first 2 trigger(I didn't write that part, just made the alerts unique)... I'm fine with that for now.  I did read something about get element id or something but I couldn't find it explained anywhere good enough for me to "get".
Please javascript only, no jquery... I'm still barely getting javascript at the moment... please explain answers so I understand how something works - I don't just want code snippets that leave me coming back with a similar question because I don't understand why a bit of code was used.

And one other question unless I should open another question for it... when you find an egg the text says `You find an Exalted *** egg nearby` or `You find a *** egg nearby`.  Is there a way to grab the `***` part from the page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add event handlers to specific elements on a page.  If the element has an `id` attribute, this is easy:

```
var element = document.getElementById( 'whatever' );

element.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
    alert( 'element clicked' );
}, true );
```

This will add the event listener to the element with the ID "whatever".

If the element doesn't have an ID attribute, you'll need to be a bit more creative.  Here's one way to do it:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );

for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
    var link = links[i];
    if ( /area=grassland/.test( link.href ) ) {
        link.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
             alert( 'grassland link clicked' );
        }, true );
    }
}
```

The `/area=grassland/` is a [regexp](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) which matches strings that contain "area=grassland" as a substring.  (You can [do a lot more with regexps](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml) if you want.)  We test it against every link (`a` element) on the page, and add the click handler to those whose `href` attribute matches the regexp.

By the want, you can get the text inside a link with `link.textContent`, if you'd prefer to match against that.  It won't work so well with image links, though.  (But you could always find, say, the first image tag inside the link with `link.getElementsByTagName( 'img' )[0]` and work from there.)

---

As for your second question, regexps are your friend there too:

```
var regexp = /You find an? (Exalted )?(.*?) egg nearby/;
var match = regexp.exec( document.body.textContent );
if ( match ) {
    if ( match[1] ) {
        alert( "Exalted egg found: " + match[2] );
    } else {
        alert( "Normal egg found: " + match[2] );
    }
}
```

See the links I gave above for how that regexp works and how to modify it to better suit your needs.

(Ps. Warning: I didn't actually test any of the code above, as I didn't feel like creating a trial account on the game site just for that.  I hope it's correct, but there might be bugs or typos in it.)

Comment: How do I find out if an element has an ID?  And I think I can guess but what's the .test?  I didn't learn that one on codecademy...  and out of curiosity, why do all eventListeners have true at the end?

Comment: Just look at the page HTML source, if you see something like `<a id="foobar" href="...">` then it has an ID. For the meaning of `regexp.test()`, see the links I gave. As for the `true`, it controls a fairly obscure detail related to the order in which different event handlers are triggered; for details, see e.g. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener). In most modern browsers, you can just leave it out if you don't care, but older browsers may require it.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! The non-ID code worked great!  And now I have new info to code a bunch of different things into this script and another one I'm not happy with! Thank you! And thanks for the VERY clear answer and explanations!

Comment: Question... the links for collecting the eggs match that test too... `http://unicreatures.com/explore.php?area=sea&gather=1&enc=473005&r=` would I just add a "and does not equal' to the if statement above?

Comment: You could just use two regexps, like `if ( /area=grassland/.test( link.href ) && !/gather=1/.test( link.href ) ) { ... }` (or just use two nested `if` statements if you prefer).  You could probably also do it with one regexp using "negative look-ahead", but this way seems simpler to me.

Comment: `x(?!y)` just found on one of those links you gave me and implemented it lol.... was going to use the `&&` but was having trouble remembering what would be repeated... always end up only adding the difference and code doesn't like that.  Thanks!

Comment: It took me this long to figure out why the code to get the egg type wasn't working since it didn't throw any errors.... ended up researching regExp and a bunch of other stuff and then finally before giving up I decided to change `document.textContent` to match the one the original coder used for the eggs `document.body.innerHTML` and with that one change it works great... thanks for the help and new commands

Comment: Oops, my mistake. You're right, `document.textContent` doesn't work; I've changed the code above to use `document.body.textContent` instead. (Using `.innerHTML` is fine too, it depends on whether you want to match the regexp against the HTML source or the rendered text. In this case it might not make any difference.)

Comment: Thanks again! Now just had to post another question because alerts are NOT the best way to run something like this lol!

Comment: Where is this code wrong? It's counting even when the second condition is false. I had to switch from regexp because I needed to use a variable in the comparison..... `for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
    var link = links[i];
    if (url.indexOf("area=")>=0 && url.indexOf("gather=")==-1) {
        link.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
localStorage.steps=Number(localStorage.steps)+1
localStorage[loc+"Steps"]=Number(localStorage[loc+"Steps"])+1
           // alert(localStorage[loc+"Steps"] +" in local"+loc);
        }, true );
  }
}`  I don't like how it took all formatting out

Comment: I think you should make that a separate question, pasting code into comments doesn't work too well as you can see.

Comment: I did... turns out it was an ADHD moment... `url` was set to the current url