# Remote browser session debugging: Is there a tool to get a “core dump” of a browser's interaction with a webpage?

Tags: debugging, browser, profiling, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

A user of my website is having a problem that I can't reproduce. It is maddening to debug, because all I can really ask the user (nontechnical person) is their OS version and browser version.

Is there an extension for Chrome/Firefox, or any other software, that can basically record the user's session with a webpage from the client perspective? Akin to everything you'd see in the Chrome Developer toolbar, recorded into a "dump" file that I could analyze? Files downloaded, DOM loaded, javascript events, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure about a extension for Chrome/FireFox but you could use software such as Windows Remote Desktop or TeamViewer if the User was willing to allow you access to their CPU.  Depending on the issue, you might also be able to check your server log files to see where the user is getting an error.

Another solution might be to write a script to keep track of what is clicked by users who visit your webpages.  I believe GreaseMonkey add on for Firefox might help you with this.

Remote Software
Source: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2091801/5-alternatives-to-logmein-free-for-remote-pc-access.html

GreasreMonkey
Source: [How to detect clicks on specific links in page with Greasemonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349721/how-to-detect-clicks-on-specific-links-in-page-with-greasemonkey)